# New cast iron has gotten strange color

Tags: cast-iron

I just got my first iron cast. I went to remove the wax and I am now in the middle of seasoning it.

So far it has gotten oil and 200°C at 1 hour, two times, and now it has a color I find strange. It looks sticky, but it ain't.

Is this normal?
And - how come are there some spots which is so clean? (see red rings)
[image]

Comment: Let me guess -- it's the same spacing as the grate that you had it sitting on when you first seasoned it?  If that's the case, it just didn't get hot enough to fully polymerize the oil in that area, so you'll need to give it a few more rounds of seasoning.

Comment: @Joe you should move your comment to an answer. That's definitely what happened.

Answer (score 7):

There is a very good chance that the spacing of the markings is the same as the grate on your oven.  (at least the ones on the right side).

The left one I'm not too sure about -- it might've been something like an oven thermometer, or just where you touched it as you were loading it into the oven.

When this happens your best option I've found is to repeat the seasoning, but with the pan right-side up this time.  You'll want to make sure that you've wiped up as much oil as you can from the working area of the pan ... otherwise you'll get a thicker coating that's more likely to scrape off with use.

Comment: Also, if you re-season it upside down you can just make sure the discolored spots are not touching the grate. That would avoid the problem of too much oil causing a thicker coating.